# Why is sorting in MySQL not working properly?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have table named `price` with datatype `varchar(25)`. In a query I fetch the values 45000, 32000, 420, 237 and 180 and I sort them in `ascending` order. It gives me the results 180, 237, 32000, 420, 45000 but I don't know why it is sorting according to first three digits if one of it is three digit number and if all numbers are 4 digit it's working fine. Any solution would be appreciated.

I have used `CAST(prix as decimal)` in Query it is still not working.

Some portion of Query and I'm sorting with prix case

```
WHEN (_flg_asc_desc = 0 AND _order_by_flg = 1) THEN CAST(a.prix as decimal)
```

See bellow

```
ORDER BY
CASE 
    WHEN (CAST(a.prix as decimal) IS NULL 
    OR CAST(a.prix as decimal) = 'NA' 
    OR CAST(a.prix as decimal) = 'N/A' 
    OR CAST(a.prix as decimal) = '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END,
CASE 
    WHEN (CAST(a.surface as decimal) IS NULL 
    OR CAST(a.surface as decimal) = 'NA' 
    OR CAST(a.surface as decimal) = 'N/A' 
    OR CAST(a.surface as decimal) = '') THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END,
CASE 
    WHEN (_flg_asc_desc = 0 AND _order_by_flg = 0) THEN a.date_last_modif 
    WHEN (_flg_asc_desc = 0 AND _order_by_flg = 1) THEN CAST(a.prix as decimal) //   <==== My case in sorting prix
    WHEN (_flg_asc_desc = 0 AND _order_by_flg = 2) THEN CAST(a.surface as decimal) 
END ASC,

CASE 
    WHEN (_flg_asc_desc = 1 AND _order_by_flg = 0) THEN a.date_last_modif 
    WHEN (_flg_asc_desc = 1 AND _order_by_flg = 1) THEN CAST(a.prix as decimal) //   <==== My case in sorting prix
    WHEN (_flg_asc_desc = 1 AND _order_by_flg = 2) THEN CAST(a.surface as decimal) 
END DESC
```

Comment: You can use a `null` for undefined pricing value. Anything else? Isn't it funny how your problem completely disappears if you use the tools that nice guys at MySQL gave you?

Comment: Well, it's your client and your project. If you can't perform simple `if(db_column == null) printf("N/A");` or similar in the language of your choice, then I really, really pity that poor client who chose you. You are considered a professional. It's just poor excuse saying that because of `N/A` you need to use wrong data type, with wrong approach for sorting and what not only because you are lazy to do one simple check when you pull the data out. Really poor excuse. I wish you good luck with future projects and may you not repeat the same mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

Because the data is a string (VARCHAR), the database is sorting alphabetically, rather than numerically. You must cast to an integer (DECIMAL) *in the order by clause* to allow numerical sorting.

If you'd like more details, please post a snippet of your code so we can see the syntax.

Comment: Wow, ok, that's complicated order by clause: and it does seem to be quite redundant and unnecessary. Also, you are comparing a dynamically case decimal to a string in many places, rendering the dynamic cast useless. As N.B. rather forthrightly points out, you should probably be using DECIMAL for this type of data rather than string. Is this something you can change?